# Programmatically change NERDTreeWinSize

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I like to change the vim-plugin NERDTreeWinSize variable programmatically.

I added the following function to my `vimrc` but nothing is happening when I call the function. Any hints?

```
fun! NerdTreeWinSize( arg )
  let g:NERDTreeWinSize=a:arg
endfunction
command! -nargs=* Ntws call NerdTreeWinSize( '<args>' )
```

I can call the function via `:Ntws 200` and wish that the `NERDTreeWinSize` changes to `200` then.

I also realized that nothing is happening when i run `let g:NERDTreeWinSize=100` in the vim command line.

But when I add the line `let g:NERDTreeWinSize=100` to my `vimrc` vim adapts the `NERDTreeWinSize`.

Comment: `g:NERDTreeWinSize` is only read once, during startup so changing its value at runtime does nothing. I suggest heading toward the plugin's issue tracker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct, and (at least my version of NERDTree) re-evaluates the `g:NERDTreeWinSize` variable when building its UI. However, the change does *not* affect open NERDTree windows, only new ones. So, you need to re-open NERDTree for the changes to take effect, maybe via

```
command! -nargs=* Ntws call NerdTreeWinSize( '<args>' ) | NERDTree
```